# ValueError on inverse transform using OrdinalEncoder with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am getting an error on the inverse_transform after fit_transform. I am trying to inverse_transform float64 back to its original datatype which is string.

getting the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("pris.csv", usecols=['judge', 'plea_orcs', 'prior_cases', 'race', 'pris_yrs'])
```

transforming string columns in csv:

```
oe = OrdinalEncoder()
df[['plea_orcs']] = oe.fit_transform(df[['plea_orcs']])
df[['judge']] = oe.fit_transform(df[['judge']])
df[['race']] = oe.fit_transform(df[['race']])
```

X and y for sklearn:

```
X = df[['plea_orcs', 'judge', 'race', 'prior_cases', 'pris_yrs']]
y = df[['to_prison']]
```

this is raising the error:

```
print(oe.inverse_transform(X.plea_orcs[0].reshape(-1,1)))
```

error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-291-11e4763a5a03> in <module>
----> 1 print(oe.inverse_transform(X.plea_orcs[0].reshape(-1,1)))

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    733         for i in range(n_features):
    734             labels = X[:, i].astype('int64', copy=False)
--> 735             X_tr[:, i] = self.categories_[i][labels]
    736 
    737         return X_tr

IndexError: index 68 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

Should I not be using OrdinalEncoding? I have several different ways but this one seems to be an error in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

```py
oe = OrdinalEncoder()
df[['plea_orcs']] = oe.fit_transform(df[['plea_orcs']])
df[['judge']] = oe.fit_transform(df[['judge']])
df[['race']] = oe.fit_transform(df[['race']])
```

In the second line, you `fit` your ordinal encoder on the column `'plea_orcs'`.  You can then `transform` that data (as you do with the convenience `fit_transform`) and `inverse_transform` the result.

But then in the third line, you re`fit` the ordinal encoder on the column `'judge'`.  This **loses all information** about `plea_orcs`, and you will no longer be able to transform test data, or inverse-transform.

## Some solutions

In increasing order of (IMO) elegance:

1. Instantiate separate ordinal encoders for each feature.
2. Use just one ordinal encoder, and fit and transform all three columns at once.
3. Use just one ordinal encoder together with a `ColumnTransformer` for selecting the appropriate columns.  Use `passthrough` for other columns, if you don't need to do any preprocessing to them.

## Off-topic...

...but consider whether ordinal encoding is appropriate: if your data isn't naturally ordered, then you're adding false relationships to your data.  See e.g. [this DS.SE post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/77880/55122).

Comment: Thank you at the moment the least elegant option has worked. I also switched to label encoding, I am not sure of what other option I have. I am newer to ML, if you could suggest something?

Comment: "Label encoding" (at least in sklearn) is the same as ordinal encoding, but meant for encoding multiclass dependent variables. One-hot encoding is the simplest and most straightforward approach.  See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/categorical-encoding for discussions around alternatives.